# How to write a function to replace #ifdef and #endif pair?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I use `#ifdef` and `#endif` a lot in my code, for example:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#define __TEST____
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"do something 1"<<std::endl;
#ifdef __TEST____

         // a 
         // lot
         // of 
         // test codes
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

The `#ifdef` and `#endif` pairs reduces code readability.
How to write a function to replace the `#ifdef` and `#endif` pairs ?
Just like this one:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#define __TEST____
#define TEST（...） { #ifdef __TEST____ {__VA_ARGS__} #endif}
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"do something 1"<<std::endl;
    TEST(
         // a 
         // lot
         // of 
         // test codes
         );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be clear, what you added in the second piece of code is not a function.

Comment: `__TEST__` identifier is reserved to the implementation. By defining it, your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @eerorika: ...unless he's working on "the implementation". (Which he clearly isn't, I just wanted to nitpick about something. ;-) )

Comment: @DevSolar in which case, defining `main` and `TEST` would be off limits, as those are reserved to the user code :)

Comment: @eerorika: Ah. :-D Damn, I should know better than to play the "funny nitpick" game before the first coffee of the day. :-D You win. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ (any version) you could just change the order of the `#ifdef` and the `#define`:

```
#ifdef __TEST__
# define TEST(...) { __VA_ARGS__ }
#else
# define TEST(...)
#endif

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"do something 1"<<std::endl;
    TEST(
         // a 
         // lot
         // of 
         // test codes
         );
    return 0;
}
```